# How to group by array index

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm trying to group an array of elements by its index divided by 4. For example, in the following input, since the indices of int_arr divided by 4 return 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, I am hoping to group them under the elements in `str_arr`, in which A corresponds to elements 1, 2, 3, 4 in `int_arr` and so on.

I am aware that I will need to convert the elements in `int_arr` to String, and that I will also need a map to hold all the elements such that the elements in the `str_arr` are the keys and the concatenated elements in `int_arr` are the values. However, I am having a hard time to group the elements `int_arr` according to their indices divided by 4, and I need some insight on that.

input:

```
int[] int_arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12};
String[] str_arr = {A, B, C, D};
```

desired output:

```
{A= 1, 2, 3, 4, B = 5, 6, 7, 8, C = 9, 19, 11, 12}
```

Comment: Please include the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could split the single dimensional integer array into a two dimensional Object Array where as the first element for each **row** of that 2D Array contains an auto-generated uppercase letter prefix string (starting from the letter **A**), and the remaining **row** elements contain the integer values values from the split integer array. In other words, if you have a integer (int[]) array which consists of **12** integer elements:

```
int[] int_arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

and you want to sequentially spit this array into segments of **4** then you would end up with a 2D Object Array (Object[][]) consisting of **3** rows with each row containing **5** columns. Always remember, the first column is optionally reserved for a prefix string:

```
[ [A, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
  [B, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
  [C, 9, 10, 11, 12] ]
```

But what if the supplied int[] array contains **14** integer elements and can not be equally divided by **4**? Then a 4th row is created within the 2D Array that contains only **3** columns, for example:

```
[ [A, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
  [B, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
  [C, 9, 10, 11, 12],
  [D, 13, 14] ]
```

But what if there are more than 26 integer elements within the int[] array, let's say **121** or more integer elements? What is used as a prefix string for each row once the prefix auto-generator passes the letter **Z**? The prefix auto-generator then produces prefix strings of:

```
AA, AB, AC, ..., AZ, 
BA, BB, BC, ..., BZ,
...................,
ZA, ZB, ZC, ..., ZZ,
AAA, AAB, AAC, ..., AAZ,
and so on, and so on...
```

The following Java method named **splitIntArrayTo2DArrayWithLetterPrefix()** will do this. Yes...I know it's a crazy long name but it's descriptive for this specific purpose. You can always change it to whatever you like:

```
/**
 * Creates a two dimensional Object array (Object[][]) from a supplied
 * single dimensional integer array (int[]) based on the supplied desired
 * number of columns for each row of the created 2D Array. The first element
 * of every row within the newly created 2D array will be a string letter
 * prefix starting from the letter 'A'. So if we have an integer array which
 * consists of:
 * <pre>
 *
 *    int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};</pre><br>
 * <p>
 * and we want to split this single dimensional array into a 2D array with
 * each row consisting of 3 columns which will actually be 4 columns because
 * the column index 0 of each row is reserved for an auto generated prefix
 * string. When this above int[] array is run through this method the return
 * 2D Object[] array will consist of:
 * <pre>
 *
 *     [A, 1, 2, 3]
 *     [B, 4, 5, 6]
 *     [C, 7, 8, 9]
 *     [D, 10, 11, 12]</pre><br>
 * <p>
 * If the single dimensional int[] array is large enough whereas the rows
 * span greater than to handle the prefix string of A to Z then the prefix
 * string automatically changes to AA to ZZ, then to AAA to ZZZ, then to
 * AAAA to ZZZZ, and so on. When the rows get to a 4 letter prefix string
 * then we're talking about several thousands of Array elements.
 *
 * @param int_arr         (Single Dimensional int[] Array) The integer array
 *                        to split.<br><br>
 *
 * @param desiredColumns  (Integer - int) The desired number of columns to
 *                        be contained within the created 2D array for each
 *                        array row. If during processing the final elements
 *                        of the int[] array does not mean the desired
 *                        columns requirement then the last row of the
 *                        returned 2D Object[][] array will contain those
 *                        elements, for example, if the supplied int[] array
 *                        contained 13 elements<pre>
 *
 *    int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};</pre><br>
 *
 * and we want to split this array into a 2D array with each row consisting
 * of 3 columns then our returned 2D Object[] array will consist of:
 * <pre>
 *
 *     [A, 1, 2, 3]
 *     [B, 4, 5, 6]
 *     [C, 7, 8, 9]
 *     [D, 10, 11, 12]
 *     [E, 13]</pre><br>
 *
 * Notice the last row, it only consists of 2 elements instead of 4 (the
 * prefix string and the final int[] array element). No array element is
 * ignored within the supplied int[] array. All elements are placed into the
 * 2D Object[][] array even if the column count for the last row is
 * short.<br>
 *
 * @param dontApplyPrefix (Optional - Boolean) Default is false. By default
 *                        the first element in each 2D array row (at index
 *                        0) is reserved for a auto-generated letter prefix
 *                        string. If true is supplied then no letter prefix
 *                        string is applied to the returned 2D Object[][]
 *                        Array, the int[] array is merely split into 
 *                        individual columnar rows as specified by the 
 *                        desiredColumns parameter argument. Nothing, true, 
 *                        false, or null can be supplied to this optional 
 *                        parameter.
 *
 * @return (Two Dimensional Object[][] Array) The created 2D Object Array.
 */
public static Object[][] splitIntArrayTo2DArrayWithLetterPrefix(int[] int_arr,
                int desiredColumns, Boolean... dontApplyPrefix) {
    boolean noPrefix = false;
    if (dontApplyPrefix != null && dontApplyPrefix.length > 0) {
        noPrefix = dontApplyPrefix[0];
    }
    if (int_arr.length == 0 || (desiredColumns < 1 && desiredColumns > int_arr.length)) {
        return null;
    }
    int availableRows = int_arr.length % desiredColumns == 0
            ? (int_arr.length / desiredColumns)
            : int_arr.length / desiredColumns + 1;

    Object[][] newArray = new Object[availableRows][];
    Object[] innerArray = new Object[!noPrefix ? desiredColumns + 1 : desiredColumns];
    String rowPrefix = "";
    int columnCount = 0;
    int rowCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < int_arr.length; i++) {
        if (columnCount == 0 && !noPrefix) {
            /* Generate a row prefix letter string for the first column of row.
               The prefix letter will always start with 'A' and increment up
               the alphabet for each new array row until 'Z' is reached at which
               point the prefix changes to 'AA', then 'AB' for the next row and
               so on until the the array creation has completed.            */
            int val = rowCount;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf((char) ('A' + (val % 26))));
            while ((val = (val / 26 - 1)) >= 0) {
                sb.append((char) ('A' + (val % 26)));
            }
            rowPrefix = sb.reverse().toString();
            innerArray[columnCount] = rowPrefix;
            columnCount++;
        }
        innerArray[columnCount] = int_arr[i];
        columnCount++;
        if (!noPrefix ? columnCount > desiredColumns : columnCount == desiredColumns) {
            newArray[rowCount] = innerArray;
            innerArray = new Object[noPrefix && int_arr.length - (i + 1) < desiredColumns ? int_arr.length - (i + 1) : noPrefix ? desiredColumns : int_arr.length - (i + 1) < desiredColumns ? int_arr.length - i : desiredColumns + 1];
            columnCount = 0;
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
    if (innerArray.length > 0 && innerArray[0] != null) {
        newArray[rowCount] = innerArray;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

---

### **How you might use (or test) the above method:**

**Generating an int[] Array for testing:**

```
int numberOfElements = 12; // Change to whatever size you want.
int[] int_arr = new int[numberOfElements]; //{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
for (int i = 0; i < int_arr.length; i++) {
    int_arr[i] = i + 1;
}
```

**Calling the method:**

```
// The number elements in a group to split the int_arr[] array into.
int desiredNumberOfColumns = 4; 
boolean dontUseAutoPrefix = false;  // Default
Object[][] myArray = splitIntArrayTo2DArrayWithLetterPrefix(int_arr, 
                           desiredNumberOfColumns, dontUseAutoPrefix);
```

**Displaying the returned array:**

```
System.out.println("Rows of the 2D Array created:");
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ") " + Arrays.toString(myArray[i]));
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Size of the Array is " + myArray.length
        + " literal rows consisting of " + myArray[0].length
        + " columns in each row");
System.out.print("where the first column holds a prefix "
        + "string and the other " + (myArray[0].length - 1)
        + " columns hold" + System.lineSeparator()
        + "integer values derived from the supplied int[] array.");
int lastRowColumnCount = myArray[myArray.length - 1].length;
System.out.println(lastRowColumnCount < desiredNumberOfColumns + 1
        ? " Keep in mind however" + System.lineSeparator()
        + "that the last array row consists of only "
        + lastRowColumnCount + " columns, one of which is the "
        + System.lineSeparator() + "prefix string. " : "");
```

**Output:**

```
Rows of the 2D Array created:
1) [A, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2) [B, 5, 6, 7, 8]
3) [C, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Size of the Array is 3 literal rows consisting of 5 columns in each row
where the first column holds a prefix string and the other 4 columns hold
integer values derived from the supplied int[] array.
```

**Displaying the returned array *any way you like*:**

```
System.out.println("Desired display as per Original Post:");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    String elementalString = Arrays.toString(myArray[i]);
    elementalString = elementalString.substring(elementalString.indexOf(",") + 1,
            elementalString.lastIndexOf("]")).trim();
    if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) { 
        sb.append(", "); 
    }
    sb.append(myArray[i][0].toString()).append(dontUseAutoPrefix ? ", " : " = ")
              .append(elementalString);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
Desired display as per Original Post:
A = 1, 2, 3, 4, B = 5, 6, 7, 8, C = 9, 10, 11, 12
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need something like this:

```
int outputLength = (int)Math.ceil((double)int_arr.length / 4);
String[] output = new String[outputLength];

int i = 0;
int integerPart = 0;

for(String label: str_arr) {
    if(i >= int_arr.length) break;
        
    StringBuilder group = new StringBuilder();
    group.append(label + "= ");

    while(i < int_arr.length && i / 4 == integerPart) {
        group.append(int_arr[i]);
        ++i;
        
        if(i / 4 == integerPart) {
            group.append(", ");
        }
    }
    
    output[integerPart] = group.toString();
    integerPart++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired output resembles a map with a key taken from `str_arr` and the value - a subarray or a sublist from `int_arr`.  It may be convenient to use Stream API for this purpose:

```java
Map<String, int[]> result = IntStream.range(0, (int)Math.ceil(int_arr.length / 4.0))
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 i -> str_arr[i],
                 i -> Arrays.copyOfRange(int_arr, i * 4, Math.min(i * 4 + 4, int_arr.length))
             ));

result.forEach((k, v) ->  System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", k, Arrays.toString(v)));
```

Output:

```
A -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
B -> [5, 6, 7, 8]
C -> [9, 10, 11, 12]
```

To get the list, another stream and `Collectors::toList` may be used instead of `Arrays::copyOfRange`:

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> mapOfLists = IntStream.range(0, (int)Math.ceil(int_arr.length / 4.0))
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 i -> str_arr[i],
                 i -> IntStream.range(i * 4, Math.min(i * 4 + 4, int_arr.length))
                    .mapToObj(j -> int_arr[j])
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
             ));
System.out.println(mapOfLists);
```

Output:

```
{A=[1, 2, 3, 4], B=[5, 6, 7, 8], C=[9, 10, 11, 12]}
```